# Unsecurity conection - Firefox - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

IDE: Visual Studio 2015
Geckodriver.exe (Version 0.19.0) - Published: 9/25/2017
Firefox version: 56.0b8 (64-bit)
Selenium webdriver version: 3.6.0

Using Selenium and C # I did as lines of code below:

```
using (FirefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver () driver)
{
driver.Navigate (). GoToUrl("https://www.teste.gov.br/seguro/loginPortal.asp");
Thread.Sleep (1000 * 60);
}
```

The page opens a message of "Your connection is not private", error "Your connection is not secure".
To resolve this issue you have already used the following codes:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile ()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
driver = new FirefoxDriver (profile)

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile ()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
driver = new FirefoxDriver (profile)

profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true);                         
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer (false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver (profile)

ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true)
ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer (false)
driver = new FirefoxDriver (ffProfile)
```

and other codes ...

But the problem continues. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR; There is no reasonable approach to solving this problem.

If it's absolutely necessary to **visit** the site only, e.g. to create a cookie, use PhantomJS. Every browser driver I've tried gives the error, and it's impossible to bypass without some sort of security exploit.

The browser is **literally letting you know the site is insecure.** Albeit its a government site, it might be compromised.

On a separate note, its probably cleaner to do this:

```
FirefoxDriver() ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
ffDriver.Navigate("myCoolSite.url");
```